# Free PHP script that downloads web pages

Tags: php, scripting, proxy

I want to know if someone knows where I can find a PHP script that does all the functions of web proxy?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how helpful this is, because your question sounds like you want a lightweight solution. However, take a look at [PHPProxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/), an open source proxy application.